# Unable to add image to Customer Asset

Tags: dynamics-crm, powerapps, dynamics-365, entities

I have a few Entities, for which I have added an IFrame inside a single column tab. The IFrame displays the image which it fetches from the url in the URL field on the same form.
For this I have added a javascript in the IFrame tag properties.It works for the Product Entity and the image is displayed in its form, however it doesn't work for Customer Asset Entity.

Here is the javascript I have used

```
function onload()
{
var url =Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_url").getValue();

 Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get("IFRAME_pic").setSrc(url);

}
```

It is unable to locate the attribute on the page and gives out the below on page load of Customer Assets:
`**Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get(...) is null**`

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is the iframe in same form tab or in another tab/section? is it uci?

Comment: @ArunVinoth Yes, the iframe is in another tab. The URL I capture is from my Custom Field on the Summary tab. I used the  same steps given @ `https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/microsoft-dynamics-crm-forum/191307/adding-an-image-to-a-product-record---is-this-possible/1100135#1100135` to add image successfully to product Form

Comment: Tell us the difference between working and not working form, try settimeout in case of delayed loading, or move your code on tab change instead of form load and set the iframe url in that particular tab expand click. If it’s UCI all tab contents won’t be rendered on form load.

Comment: yes it is UCI. For both the cases, I used a separate tab to put in a IFrame which has img src as the attribute value of URL field on the landing tab. I have edited the question to add the comparisons.